# How do I decide if a set is a vector subspace?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let's say we have the set $M = \{ x \in \mathbb R^3 : 3x_1 - x_2 -2x_3 = 1 \}$ and I have to test if M is a vector subspace of $\mathbb R^3$ .

How do I proceed? Going after my intuition, I would say it isn't since the expression pretty much looks like a plane, but how do I prove that formally?

Comment: Is $0 \in M$? ${}{}{}$

Comment: That expression defines a plane, but the plane does not pass through origin, thus is not a subspace.

Comment: didn't  you like the interpretation as the level set $M=f^{-1}(1)$ of the function$$f(x_1,x_2,x_3)=3x_1-x_2-2x_3,$$?

Comment: what do you mean? I didn't downvote you if you mean that

Comment: I answered: <<*Here $M$ is a level set of the function 
$$f(x_1,x_2,x_3)=3x_1-x_2-2x_3,$$
i.e. $M=f^{-1}(1)$ and it 
is a plane which doesn't pass through the origin, then isn't a vector subspace.*>> But some one downvoted me.

Comment: I am not blaming you, i only mean that you could consider my idea reading at least herein comments. And i like upvotes yes, but i hate to be down-voted that why i deleted in answers.

Answer (score 3):

To check that a set $M$ is a subspace, you usually need to check that the answer to *all* of the following three questions is "yes":

a) Is $(0,0,0)$ an element of $M$?

b) If $v_{1}$ and $v_{2}$ are in $M$, is $v_{1} + v_{2}$?

c) If $v$ is in $M$, and $c$ is any real number, is $cv$ in $M$?

Hint: I listed the things you have to check in this order for a reason.  Check a.  If a fails to hold, then you don't need to do any more work because you will know that $M$ is not a subspace!

Comment: Okay, only these 3 ? Because I was(/am) confused about what to check ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space#Definition )

Comment: @Christian Yes only those three when determining if a set is a *subspace* of a given vector space.  Please see this article (go to the Definition section): http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_subspace

Answer (score 2):

If $M$ is a subspace, then it contains the zero vector of $\mathbb R^3$: $\;\;\begin{pmatrix} x_1\\x_2\\x_3\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 0\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}$.

Does $$3(0) - (0) - 2(0) = 1\;\;?$$

I.e., Does $M$ contain the zero vector? If no, then $M$ cannot be a vector space.

Answer (score 0):

Subset $M\subseteq V$ is subspace of $V$ if it is vector space with operations from $V$. One could assume that all axioms of vector space need to be checked, but this is not the case; to prove that $M\subseteq V$ is a subspace, it is actually enough to check this condition:

> $(1)$ For any $\alpha,\beta\in\mathbb{R}$ and for any vectors
>   $v,w\in M$, *linear combination* $\alpha v + \beta w\in M$.

This is because all the axioms of vector space are satisfied for any subset $M$ of a vector space $V$ *except* that $M$ contains zero vector, additive inverses and that subset $M$ is closed under scalar multiplication and addition (which means I could potentially multiply by scalar or add vectors in $M$ but produce a vector not in $M$; this is actually *essential* for any set to be a vector space and it might be obscured by the fact that this is implicitly assumed for any vector space because scalar multiplication and addition are usually given as functions with codomain $V$, but nevertheless, all vector spaces must satisfy this criteria). These are all implied by $(1)$. Hence, you do not need to check any axioms for your subset, except the condition $(1)$ which can be broken down in two pieces:

> $(2)$ For any vectors $v,w\in M$, their sum $v+w$ is in $M$.
>   $(3)$
>   For any $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$ and any $v\in M$, we have $\alpha v\in M$.

It might be a good exercise for you to show that:

- $(1)$ implies $(2)$ and $(3)$
- $(2)$ and $(3)$ (together) imply $(1)$
- $(1)$ and $(3)$ (separately) imply that $0\in M$
- $(1)$ and $(3)$ (separately) imply that $M$ contains additive inverses

In addition, these conditions ensure that if I multiply by scalar or add vectors in $M$, I will always stay in $M$, and thus making $M$ a vector space.

Now, $(1)$ is the most compact way to check that some subset *is* a subspace, but it might not be the best approach to show that it *is not*. To see that something is not a subspace, I recommend that you follow user46944's answer, first checking if $0$ is in your subset, then checking conditions $(2)$ and $(3)$ and to try to find counterexamples using these, instead of $(1)$.

Answer (score 0):

To check if a set ($M$) is a subspace of a vector space (E,K) (where $K=\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$) you must check if $0\in M$, $x\in M \implies \lambda x \in M \ \ \ \forall \lambda \in K$ and $x,y\in M \implies x+y\in M$, or for short for all $\alpha ,\beta \in K$ and all $x,y\in M$ you hace $$\alpha x+ \beta y \in M$$
in your case since the zero (of $\mathbb{R}^3$) isn't in M, M isn't a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$